# How sensitivity analysis can be done for 2 parameters in Python for a tree

Tags: python, analysis

I have the data in tree format such as following:

```
tree = {
    'Top Node': {
        'Percentage': 0.95,
        'Value': 1000,
        'Node A': {
            'Percentage': 0.98,
            'Value': 300,
            'Node A.1': {'Percentage': 0.2, 'Value': 200},
            'Node A.2': {'Percentage': 0.3, 'Value': 200},
            'Node A.3': {'Percentage': 0.5, 'Value': 250}
        },
        'Node B': {
            'Percentage': 0.95,
            'Value': 500,
            'Node B.1': {'Percentage': 0.5, 'Value': 220},
            'Node B.2': {'Percentage': 0.2, 'Value': 60},
            'Node B.3': {'Percentage': 0.3, 'Value': 90}
        },
        'Node C': {
            'Percentage': 0.93,
            'Value': 200,
            'Node C.1': {'Percentage': 0.5, 'Value': 45},
            'Node C.2': {'Percentage': 0.25, 'Value': 22.5},
            'Node C.3': {'Percentage': 0.25, 'Value': 22.5}
        }
    }
}
```

`Top Node` is made up of multiple nodes (`Node A`, `Node B`, and `Node C` in this example). Each node has value and percentage value. Top Node's percentage value is average of percentage values of nodes A, B, and C whereas Top Node's Value parameter is sum of values of sub-nodes (A, B, and C). Same method is applied to level 3 nodes (A.1, B.1, C.1, etc.) to calculate level 2 nodes' `Percentage` and `Value` parameters. Now, how can I do sensitivity analysis based on `Percentage` and `Value` such that changing node values at level 3 will have highest impact on value of `Percentage` of `Top Node`.

I tried to perform weighting method where weight is calculated at each level by multiplying `Percentage` and `Value`. However, I am not sure that how to move ahead to calculate effect of these weighting values on accuracy of `Top Node`.